# Dojo, DataGrid and disable row selection

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a little problem with the Datagrid.

I Want to disable the row selection in my datagrid but I don't know how to do it.
I tried setAttribute('disabled',true) and Co. but it's not working.

So if you have any idea to do it .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the selectionMode attribute to "none" on the grid.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" data-dojo-props="selectionMode:'none'">
    <!-- [...] -->
</div>
```

or, programmatically :

```
grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
          id: 'grid',
          store: store,
          structure: layout,
          selectionMode : 'none'},
      someNode);
```